# ld fails in: libcrypto.a fails relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shared-libraries, ld, centos6, libcrypto

I'm getting

> linking shared-object rubyeventmachine.so
>   /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(bio_lib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [rubyeventmachine.so] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2

When executting a

> bundle install

On CentOS release 6.4
How can I fix it using openssl istalled using yum install?

Package instaled

> openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64

and

> openssl-devel-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64